# C++11 RegEx Matching - I can't get it to work properly

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

```
bool match=0;
string pattern, domain="sub1.example.org";
while(res->next())
{
   pattern.append("(.+\\.)?");
   pattern.append(res->getString(1));
   std::regex RE(pattern);
   cout << pattern << "-" << domain << endl;
   pattern.clear();
   if((match=regex_match(domain, RE)))
      break;
}
```

That one above does not match, altough output is this:

```
(.+\.)?example.org-sub1.example.org
(.+\.)?example.orgg-sub1.example.org
(.+\.)?sdasd.com-sub1.example.org
```

I guess I am too sleepy or something, can somebody help me out?

EDIT:
gcc 4.6.3

Comment: Maybe you are sleepy, because you didn't post the value of `domain` nor the definition of `pattern` or `domain`.

Comment: @rodrigo, Both std::string and they contain what output contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU libstdc++'s implementation of `<regex>` is incomplete. See [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).

Comment: Or Microsoft. Their implementation is complete.

Comment: @PeteBecker MS is hardly an option for decent C++11 language support, nor cross-platformness.

Comment: @rubenvb - uh, yes, one problem with "cross-platformness" as it relates to regex is that MS has a complete implementation and gcc doesn't. Sure makes it hard to port standard-conforming code from MS to gcc.

Comment: @PeteBecker as the OP says: Boost. No issues there.

Comment: @rubenvb - umm, one issue is that Boost requires separate installation and maintenance, while the standard version comes with the compiler.

Comment: @PeteBecker Just include the Boost stuff in your project. No maintenance. No hassle, works everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the implementation. I get the same result, but if I remove the '?' from the regular expression it matches. I can't think of any reason that saying "0 or 1 of these" instead of "1 of these" would fail when the latter succeeds.